# Perform menu bar actions

Tags: c++, windows

I have a test program that I use to play around with menu bars.  It looks like this:

(There's supposed to be an image here.  If there isn't, it's just a small window with a menu bar.)
[image]
<sub>(source: [000webhostapp.com](https://randomcounternet.000webhostapp.com/pastebasket/menu%20bar%20test.png))</sub>

My code is very simple and I have all I need design wise.  The only thing I need help with is performing actions when they're clicked.

Here's what I have:

```
switch (message)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HMENU hMunubar = CreateMenu();
        HMENU hFile = CreateMenu();
        HMENU hEdit = CreateMenu();
        HMENU hHelp = CreateMenu();

        /* Create the "File" tab */
        AppendMenu(hMunubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR) hFile,    "File");

        AppendMenu(hFile, MF_STRING, (UINT_PTR) 1,      TEXT("Exit      Alt+f4"));


        /* Create the "Edit" tab */
        AppendMenu(hMunubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR) hEdit,    "Edit");

        AppendMenu(hEdit, MF_STRING, (UINT_PTR) 2,      TEXT("Copy      Ctrl+C"));
        AppendMenu(hEdit, MF_STRING, (UINT_PTR) 3,      TEXT("Cut       Ctrl+X"));
        AppendMenu(hEdit, MF_STRING, (UINT_PTR) 4,      TEXT("Paste     Ctrl+V"));


        /* Create the "Help" tab */
        AppendMenu(hMunubar, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR) hHelp,    "Help");

        AppendMenu(hHelp, MF_STRING, (UINT_PTR) 5,      TEXT("Visit Forum"));

        SetMenu(hwnd, hMunubar);
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage (0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I learned how to create the menu off of [this youtube video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QoQZ0trJ1s) The guy explained in depth how to CREATE the menu, but not so much how to do anything with it. Right now, all I want it to do is exit when I click File->Exit.

I tried using this in my `switch (message)` function:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    if(LOWORD(wParam) == 1){
        return 0;
    }
        break;
}
```

But that did not work.  How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first *if* expression checks if the incoming WM_COMMAND message refers to a menu command. The second *if* expression checks the menu identifier, so you can apply different actions to different menu options.

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    if (!HIWORD(wParam))
    {
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == 1) // Checks for the menu identifier of the Exit option
        {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I recommend you to create macro definitions, or actually since you tagged your question as C++, constant variables to provide the numeric constants representing the menu identifiers with meaningful names.